# Call function outside of @client.event (discord.py)

Tags: discord.py

I'm making a discord bot to play a game, using direct and open message commands to register player actions.

The message event handler is here. When getting a message to start the game, it'll start doing various things to get the game running.

```
import discord
import random
import datetime
client = discord.Client()


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))


@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return


    if "!ww start" == message.content.lower() and not(discord.ChannelType == "private"):
        # Do stuff
        night(message)


    if "!ww save " in message.content.lower() and discord.ChannelType == "private":
        save(message)


    if "!ww kill " in message.content.lower() and discord.ChannelType == "private":
        kill(message)


    if "!ww vote " in message.content.lower() and discord.ChannelType == "private":
        vote(message)


    if "!ww view " in message.content.lower() and discord.ChannelType == "private":
        view(message)


    if "!ww remove" == message.content.lower():
        remove(message)


    if ("!ww add" == message.content.lower()):
        add(message)


    if (message.content == '!ww count'):
        count(message)

    if discord.ChannelType == "private":
        night(message)

    day(message)
'''

One example of a function I want to call is here, like others it makes use of the message and channel. This is in line with the above block of code.
'''
async def night(message):
    with open("GameData.txt", mode="r", encoding="utf-8") as my_file:
        gameData = my_file.read().replace('\n', '')
    if gameData[-1] != " ":
        gameData = gameData + " "
    gameData = list(gameData.split(", "))

    if gameData[4] != "Night":
        return
    for i in range(len(gameData)):
        if gameData[i] == ".":
            return

    # Read who was killed
    channel = client.get_channel(int(gameData[1]))
    if gameData[2] == gameData[0]:
        await channel.send("Someone was saved in the night")
    else:
        killed = gameData[2]
        await channel.send(killed + " was killed in the night")
        remove(message)

    await message.channel.send("It is now day, the game will continue when you all make your decision")
    nightClean()


client.run("No")
```

Eventually there is a loop between two functions that call each other once run. They will only run when other inputs have been made through additional message inputs handled in other functions.

Currently I'm getting an error saying: RuntimeWarning: "coroutine 'day' was never awaited  day(message)" as with another function.

How can I work around this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To create a command use:

```
@client.command()
async def command_name(ctx, commands args like user to ban etc):
    Do stuff
```

And this is a command. Don't use the on_message function.